# How to handle a single "-" (dash) in OptionParser?

Tags: ruby, optionparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby OptionParser empty switch “-” behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037585/ruby-optionparser-empty-switch-behavior)

I've wrote code that uses OptionParser to handle command line input gracefully. I am facing two major hits.

1. Passing an empty switches '-' doesn't give an error.
2. The program requires two mandatory switches, but it accepts one switch without complaining!

For the first case I've done this:

```
opts.on('-', '--') do |value|
  $stderr.print "Invalid empty switch"
  exit 1
end
```

EDIT (Jumped on success too soon):
It works in the case of empty switch, but also if the switch is not empty. How can I do this?

For the second case, I've looked around for a solution within the OptionParser.new block but I couldn't find one. Doing it outside the OptionParser.new block is the normal way?